# Access output of intermediate layer for each input image and feed as input to another model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have made multiple models using model subclassing approach. Now I need to get the intermediate layer output of say Model1 and give it as input to another model say Model2.

My Model1 code is like this :

```
    class Cmodel(keras.Model):
       
        def __init__(self):
            super(Cmodel,self).__init__(name = "CustomMod")
            self.conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3 , padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')
            self.conv2 = Conv2D(16, 3 , padding = 'same', activation = 'relu')
            #Intilizing other layers
        
       def call(self,input_):   
            conv1 = self.conv1(input_)
            conv2 = self.conv2(conv1) # I need the output of this layer
            #Other layers
            classifier = self.dense(x)  #last layer
            return classifier

Model1 = CModel()
Model1.compile(loss = categorical_focal_loss(), optimizer = 'adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history  = Model1.fit(train_generator, epochs = 1, validation_data = validation_generator)
```

I need to get the output of conv2 for every input image. This extracted output will then be processed and fed as input to Model2.

I have tried two approaches to get the output of the intermediate layer but both did not work as expected. The approaches are:

1. Not so good way. Using Model1.input and Model1.get_layer(layername).output, wrapping them up using keras.Model. This returned an error.

> Model1_output_layer = Model1.get_layer("feature_maps").output
>
> m =  keras.Model(inputs = Model1.input, outputs=Model1_output_layer)

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-cbc543941051> in <module>
      1 Model1_output_layer = Model1.get_layer("feature_maps").output
----> 2 m =  keras.Model(inputs = Model1.input, outputs=Model1_output_layer)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in input(self)
   2042     """
   2043     if not self._inbound_nodes:
-> 2044       raise AttributeError('Layer ' + self.name +
   2045                            ' is not connected, no input to return.')
   2046     return self._get_node_attribute_at_index(0, 'input_tensors', 'input')

AttributeError: Layer CustomMod is not connected, no input to return.
```

2. Another way I tried to store the output of the intermediate layer is using a variable store of the class CModel, i.e,  inside the call function of the model subclass itself. This stored the intermediate layer output but for only one batch.

Please suggest some way to store the intermediate layer output of the model for every train input image.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67599150/10878733) might help.

Comment: y = Input(shape = (64,64,3))

for layer in Model1:
    if layer.name=="feature_maps":
        feature = layer

Error: Cmodel' object is not iterable//

I think due to model subclassing it is unable to iterate. Can you suggest some other way ?